# How to find all rational points on a given ellipse

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Say the ellipse is given as $2x^2+y^2=3$. How to find all rational points on it? Some detailed explanation will be great. I am really lost in this chapter.

Comment: $$3-2x^2=y^2\ge0\iff2x^2\le3$$

Comment: Take a look at  my solution for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856758/solving-a23b2-c2/856801#856801

Answer (score 5):

Once you've found one rational solution, in this case $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$, you can find all rational solutions by taking any rational direction $(n,m)$ with $n,m$ relatively prime, we look for solutions $(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)+t(n,m)$ and solve for $t$ in:

$$2(x_0+nt)^2 + (y_0+mt)^2 = 3$$

Substituting $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$, we get:

$$(2 + 4nt + 2n^2t^2) + (1+2mt + m^2t^2)=3$$

Or:

$$t(4n+2n^2t + 2m + m^2t)=0$$

Solving, we get:

$$t=-\frac{2m+4n}{m^2+2n^2}$$

So $$x=1+nt = \frac{m^2+2n^2}{m^2+2n^2}-\frac{2mn+4n^2}{m^2+2n^2} = \frac{m^2-2mn-2n^2}{m^2+2n^2}$$
and:
$$y = 1+mt = \frac{m^2+2n^2}{m^2+2n^2}-\frac{2m^2+4mn}{m^2+2n^2}=\frac{2n^2-4mn-m^2}{m^2+2n^2}$$

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether there is _any_ rational point on given ellipse?

Comment: I think there is a way, but I don't remember it. @donaastor

Comment: Can you please try to remember anything? Anything that I can search online?

Comment: There I found a paper that explains it briefly: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www3.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_1355/Rational%2520Points%2520on%2520Conics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi1p4nqmIjvAhXRz4UKHR_bAIcQFjADegQIEBAC&usg=AOvVaw1tS361O5qK1p6XcLnO57WA&cshid=1614364771389 :)